# problem passing 0 as command-line argument

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I've just noticed a strange behavior of perl5 (5.10.0) when I passed 0 as the command-line argument to a script, which assigns it to a variable. The problem I encountered is that if I give the variable a default value in my script which is greater than 0, say 1, then I can pass any value except 0 to override the default value 1.

Following is the code of 'test.pl' I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w  
my $x = shift || 1;  
print "x is $x\n";
```

Following are the commands and ouputs when I tested it:

```
$ ./test.pl 2  
x is 2  
$ ./test.pl 0  
x is 1
```

I'd appreciate if anyone can shed light on this. Thanks. wwl

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want `$x` to have the value of "1" in case no argument is provided, use this:

```
my $x = shift // 1;
```

From perldoc perlop:

> "//" is exactly the same as "||",
>          except that it tests the left hand side's definedness instead of its
>          truth.

Note: the defined-or operator is available starting from 5.10 (released on December 18th, 2007)

Comment: I have a feeling this was introduced in quite a recent version of Perl, can you say which one?  Then I'll +1.

Comment: @gbacon: Thanks.  Since quite a few of us are still on earlier versions, could you mention this in your answer please eugene y?  Thanks.

Comment: Thank eveyone who answered. I didn't expect get an answer so quickly. Thanks, eugene, I guess you are the first one to answer.

Answer (score 7):

The expression `shift || 1` chooses the rhs iff the lhs evaluates to "false". Since you are passing 0, which evaluates to "false", `$x` ends up with the value 1.

Answer (score 6):

The best approach is the one in eugene's and Alexandr's answers, but if you're stuck with an older perl, use

```
my $x = shift;
$x = 1 unless defined $x;
```

Because you have a single optional argument, you could examine `@ARGV` in scalar context to check how many command-line arguments are present. If it's there, use it, or otherwise fall back on the default:

```
my $x = @ARGV ? shift : 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

use defined-or operator, because string "0" is defined, but not evaluated as true.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w  
my $x = shift // 1;  
print "x is $x\n";
```

Comment: Yes, but as gbacon mentions in a comment elsewhere, this does require Perl 5.10 or later.

Comment: j_random_hacker: Wayne is using 5.10.0, which is 2.5 years old.

Answer (score 0):

In this line `my $x = shift || 1;` the shift failed the test and therefore the conditional logical OR `||` was executed and assigned 1 to it... as per the page on [shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) the value was 0 which implies empty array....